# Ansible get index list

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I m using ansible to create a playbook to install my project in terms of prompt parameters.

I can install 2 applications with this script, I prompt which one at the beginning and then I need to get good ssh port because applications have different port.

```
ssh_smx_ports:
  - pds: 8103
  - activemq: 8102
```

when script is started:

```
vars_prompt:
- name: "type_smx"
  prompt: "cible? (pds,activemq)"
  private: no
```

after I need to create pass this port to another command:

```
 name: install bundle on {{ type_smx }}
 tags: ssh
 command: sudo /servicemix/servicemix/bin/client -h {{ inventory_hostname }} -a {{ ssh_smx_ports[type_smx]  }} -u smx -p {{ ssh_smx_pass }} 'install mybundle'
```

but with this I got this error:

> fatal: []: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute u'pds'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/env/install_version.yml': line 60, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n       - "{{ type_smx }}"\n   - name: Add url on servicemix {{ type_smx }}\n     ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - "{{ foo }}"\n"}

how can I access to the correct port element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a list with two elements:

```
ssh_smx_ports:
  - pds: 8103
  - activemq: 8102
```

You refer to it with `ssh_smx_ports[type_smx]` like it was a dictionary:

```
ssh_smx_ports:
  pds: 8103
  activemq: 8102
```

Comment: ho no! i think i have try this but got an error :( now its working, in fact i test many case and perhaps i miss something! thanks for your reactivity